# jquery mobile AJAX call from listview

Tags: php, ajax, jquery-mobile

I have a table populated with two types of php variables from a single query. I want the reader to see the table with typeA variables, then switch to the same table but with viewB.

The reader can switch views from a little popup menu, which has list items "View A" and "View B"

I am trying to accomplish the view switch via an AJAX call, but it's not working. Drop down the "eye" menu, select "View B," and nothing happens.

What's not right about this? Any help would be warmly welcomed.

php:

```
<?php
$sql = //select all type-A and type-B columns//

{// process $sql results, return type-A and type-B variables  }

$view = $_REQUEST['name'];
if ($view == 'viewA'){// include('table.php'); echo $table, populated with type-A variables  }
if ($view == 'viewB') {// include('table.php'); echo $table, populated with type-B variables   }

?>
```

... and here's the js and html:

```js
   $(function() {

     $('#popupSwitchView').change(function() {
       var theView = $.trim($('.theView').val());

       if (theView.length > 0) {
         $.ajax({
           type: 'POST',
           url: 'file.php',
           data: ({
             name: theView
           }),
           cache: false,
           dataType: 'text',
           success: onSuccess
         });
       }
     });

     $('#resultLog').ajaxError(function(event, request, settings, exception) {
       $('#resultLog').html('Error Calling: ' + settings.url + '<br />HTTP Code: ' + request.status);
     });

     function onSuccess(data) {
       $('#resultLog').html(data);
     }

   });
```

```html
<div data-role='page'>


  <a href='#popupSwitchView' class=' ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-eye ui-btn-icon-notext  ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon ui-btn-inline' data-transition='turn' data-rel='popup' data-inline='true'>Switch view</a>

  <div data-role='popup' id='popupSwitchView' data-theme='none'>
    <ul data-role='listview'>
      <li><a href='#' data-role='button' class='ui-btn-active switchview' name='theView' value='viewA'>View A</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href='#' data-role='button' class='switchview' name='theView' value='viewB'>View B</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: thanks @HPierce, edited in the question.

Comment: Also, `{ -- comments -- }` is not syntaxically valid for PHP. If you're trying to comment, use `// comments` or `/* comments */`. I'm assuming you also meant `if ($view == 'viewB')` instead of `if ($view = 'viewB')`.

Comment: thanks for that too, I was unsure how to indicate comments when giving examples here in Stack. And yes, I did mean to put the "==", edited now.

Comment: Use `click` not `change`.